# How to implement *load-fn* for :requires in bootstrapped clojurescript

Tags: clojurescript

```
(ns scratch
  (:require [cljs.js :as cjs]))
;Let's setup a simple clojurescript string eval that supports namespaces:

(def current-ns 'cljs.user)

(def compiler-state (cjs/empty-state))

(defn eval-text [text]
  (println string)
  (cjs/eval-str compiler-state text current-ns
                {:eval cjs/js-eval
                 :ns current-ns
                 :context :expr
                 :def-emits-var true}
                (fn [result]
                  (set! current-ns (:ns result))
                  (println result))))

(eval-text "(ns a.a)")
(eval-text "(defn add [a b] (+ a b))")
(eval-text "(add 4 4)")

;I can refer to the function from another namespace explicitly with no problem
(eval-text "(ns x.x)")
(eval-text "(a.a/add 6 6)")

;However when I do
(eval-text "(ns b.b (:require [a.a :refer [add]]))")
```

On the last line I get:

```
{:error #error {:message Could not require a.a, :data {:tag :cljs/analysis-error}, :cause #object[Error Error: No *load-fn* set]}}
```

So I have to create my own https://cljs.github.io/api/cljs.js/#STARload-fnSTAR
and pass it into the :load compiler option to handle this :require even though the compiler state already knows about my namespace as I can call the fully qualified function from another namespace.. Correct?

What is the best way to do that?

Should I create maps that store namespace->source-code from previously evaled code and get namespace->analysis-cache from the compiler state and pass these into the :source and :cache callbacks of my custom load function?

Is there a better / more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the answer:

The :load option of eval-str can be set to the following function:

```
(defn load-dep [opts cb]
  (cb {:lang :js :source ""})
```

And it will quite happily resolve. This isn't really apparent from the documentation that the callback can return this value when the namespace/var is already in the compiler state so I'll leave the question here.